# What are duas? Are they the things that you want or the things that you need?

Tags: salat, hadith, dua, shaitan

The thing is that I heard that Allah loves being asked, right. Unlike humans, right? Does Allah love being "nagged"?

What does dua mean?

Does dua mean making a wish or requesting?

If so, does Allah like which dua better? Asking what you want like your heart's desires or what you need does he like the dua which praises him? I.E. "La illaha."

Or does Allah love All three duas the same?

Will he give more attention to the duas that you need or the praising dua over the what you wish for?

I am being discouraged and depressed and have been losing hope in my duas.

My duas are not for this world but in the Afterlife but I am afraid I won't get it. I know Allah can do it but will he?

Comment: Doesn't this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dua already cover most if not all your Questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all three aspects in one dua.

1. It's good to start your dua with the praise and glorification of Allah swt and sending blessings on the Prophet Muhammad and his holy family.
2. Then Ask Allah for forgiveness for your fellow believers and yourself.
3. Then it's good to pray for your brothers and sisters in faith  for everything they need or want (Everything which is good and halal).
4. At the end of your dua you should ask for yourself, doesn't matter whether your wish is big or small.
5. Finish your dua by sending once again blessings on the Prophet Muhammad and his holy family and the last should be: By Your Mercy,oh the Most merciful of the Merciful.

Allah swt loves to hear your voice especially in the night when everybody is at sleep. Try to be in a state between fear and hope. Fear of His punishment and hope for His mercy.

> The Prophet (s)said: Supplication (dua) is the weapon of the believer, the pillar of religion, and the light of the heavens and the earth. [al-Kafi, v.2, p.468,no.1]

*Never lose hope in your dua and keep on doing it!!!!!!*

Comment: It is indeed a constructive and significant sentence as you correctly remarked "Never lose hope in your dua and keep on doing it!" ________ Hopefully all of us never lose hope ... God bless you for nice answer, especially for the nice hadith of al-Kafi ...